# Changing preprocessed values during compile time

Tags: c, compilation, macros, c-preprocessor

I have written some code using pre processor directives to skip some statements to be executed.But My C code inside main is interested to change previously #defined values and assign new values as per condition and also change the result of pre processed statements too during run time.In short I have to change the pre processed statements during run time. How can I do this?

Comment: Show some code. Your question is unclear. Read about [C preprocessing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) & [cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/). You probably cannot do what you want (because *compile* time & *run* time are different and may happen on different computers with *cross-compiling*). **Improve your question** (by editing it), say more about your OS and system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In short I have to change the pre processed statements during run time

This is **impossible**. Read about [C preprocessing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) & [cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/). Compile-time and run-time are different (and the compiled code could even run on a different machine, read more about [cross-compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler)). If using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), use `gcc -C -E foo.c > foo.i` to preprocess your `foo.c` source file into `foo.i` preprocessed form (and then use an editor or a page to look inside that generated `foo.i`)

Perhaps you want to load additional code at runtime. This is not possible with pure C99 standard code. Perhaps your operating system offers [dynamic loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading). POSIX specifies [`dlopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html). You might also want to use [JIT compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) techniques to construct machine code at runtime, e.g. with libraries like [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), [asmjit](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit), [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/), [libjit](https://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/), [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), ...

Read also about [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) languages. Consider coding in Common Lisp (e.g. with [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/)).

Perhaps you want to customize your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/).

Comment: Thanks for clever answer.So I should give it try in different way.:-)

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. Preprocessing happens before compile-time.

The compiler only sees the result of the preprocessor, nothing more.